# In R, How do I extract certain rows from a list of data sets?

Tags: r, list

```
> str(pc)
'data.frame':   562 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ id        : int  1 2 3 4 5 10 12 17 19 22 ...
 $ gender    : chr  "M" "F" "M" "M" ...
 $ birth_year: int  1973 1974 1937 1943 1958 1958 1940 1973 1971 1950 ...
 $ type      : chr  "spontaneous SAH" "traumatic SAH" "spontaneous SAH" "traumatic SAH" ...
 $ admit_year: int  2011 2011 2016 2012 2018 2017 2010 2018 2016 2018 ...
 $ admit_date: chr  "2011-06-22" "2011-12-19" "2016-12-06" "2012-10-28" ...
 $ admitage  : int  38 37 79 69 60 59 70 45 45 68 ...
 $ death_date: chr  NA NA NA "2012-10-28" ...
 $ death_year: int  NA NA NA 2012 NA NA NA NA 2016 NA ...
```

Hello. I have a list that looks like this. The column "id" indicates patients IDs. But there are rows with the same ID because some patients got admitted to the hospital several times. How do I delete the duplicates and leave one row per ID?
I tried this

```
c <- unique(pc$id)
```

to extract the "id" numbers, but I don't know what to do next.
I'm a beginner, so I would appreciate it if you could explain it to me with easy codes!

EDIT: I want to make one list containing the ones with the initial admitted dates of the patients, and another list containing the ones with the final admitted dates?
How can I do that? This list is in ID order, but if one patient got admitted multiple times, the date is not necessarily in chronological order. I'd like to know how I can achieve that just by using !duplicated.

Comment: Try `pc[!duplicated(pc),]`

Comment: Or `pc[!duplicated(pc$id),]`

Comment: For a list containing the ones with the final admitted years try `pc[!duplicated(pc$id, fromLast = TRUE),]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work : `pc[!duplicated(pc$id),]`. It will by default keep the first occurence.

Comment: thank you! then what should I do if I have to make one list containing the ones with the initial admitted years of the patients, and another list containing the ones with the final admitted years?

Comment: @Hamza's solution can be used. Or something like `pc[!rev(duplicated(rev(pc$id))),]`.

Comment: this list is not in chronological order (of the admission years). Um, then what exactly does the second code you wrote do?

Comment: I'd like to rearrange this according to the chronological order and then apply the two codes that extract the initial years and final years (separately). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~gender, ~birth_year, ~admit_year,
  1,    "M",     1973,     2014,    
  2,    "F",     1974,    2016,     
  3,    "M",     1958,     2013,
  2,     "F",     1974,     2017,
  1,     "M",    1973,    2011,
  1,     "M",    1973,    2020,
  1,     "M",    1973,    2018,
  2,     "F",     1974,     2009,
)

data
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     id gender birth_year admit_year
  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1 M            1973       2014
2     2 F            1974       2016
3     3 M            1958       2013
4     2 F            1974       2017
5     1 M            1973       2011
6     1 M            1973       2020
7     1 M            1973       2018
8     2 F            1974       2009
```

#### to keep the first and last row (first admit year and last admit year) by id

```
df <- data %>% 
  # I will keep the patient with the last admit year
  arrange(admit_year) %>% 
  # I group by id
  group_by(id) %>% 
  # to keep the first and last row (first admit year and last admit year) by id
  slice(unique(c(1, n())))

df
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
     id gender birth_year admit_year
  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1 M            1973       2011
2     1 M            1973       2020
3     2 F            1974       2009
4     2 F            1974       2017
5     3 M            1958       2013
```

#### to keep the last row (last admit year) by id

```
df2 <- data %>% 
  # I will keep the patient with the last admit year
  arrange(admit_year) %>% 
  # I group by id
  group_by(id) %>% 
  # to keep the last row (last admit year) by id
  slice(n())

df2
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
     id gender birth_year admit_year
  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1 M            1973       2020
2     2 F            1974       2017
3     3 M            1958       2013
```

#### to keep the first row (first admit year) by id

```
df3 <- data %>% 
  # I will keep the patient with the last admit year
  arrange(admit_year) %>% 
  # I group by id
  group_by(id) %>% 
  # to keep the first row (first admit year) by id
  slice(1)

df3
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
     id gender birth_year admit_year
  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1 M            1973       2011
2     2 F            1974       2009
3     3 M            1958       2013
```

Comment: Thank you Hamza. But my list actually has 562 rows- how do I enter them all into the tibble?